# Android: App working fine on one device and not working on another

Tags: android, permissions, compatibility

I got one problem, my app is working fine on my [Galaxy Tab 7.7 GT-P6800](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_p6800_galaxy_tab_7_7-4136.php), which i am using for debugging purposes, and on my [Galaxy Pocket](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_pocket_s5300-4612.php) it running and creating a folder to place the file and even taking input and all that things but it isn't creating the file. I am developing in eclipse and the build SDK for the app is Android 2.3.3 (API 10).

The code for the app is given below, cannot find what the problem is...

```
package com.android.app1;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//Timestamp for file name e.g. Data_7-19-2012
SimpleDateFormat s1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy_hh:mm:ss");
final String format1 = s1.format(new Date()); 

final public String FileName = "Data_"+format1+".csv";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText addbarcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
addbarcode.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
    {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                switch (keyCode)
                {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:

                        //to get Timestamp
                        SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
                        String format = s.format(new Date());

                        //get barcode in a variable
                        Editable barcode = addbarcode.getText();

                        final String DATASTRING = new String(""+barcode+","+format+"");



                        try
                        {
                            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "BarcodeData");

                            if (!root.exists()) {
                                root.mkdirs();

                            }

                        //Showing file directory
                        TextView etDir= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                            etDir.setText(root.toString());


                            File gpxfile = new File(root, FileName);

                            BufferedWriter bW;

                            bW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(gpxfile, true));
                            bW.write(DATASTRING);
                            bW.newLine();
                            bW.flush();
                            bW.close();

                        }
                        catch(IOException e)
                        {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                        }
            String readString = new String(DATASTRING);
                    TextView etData= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

                    etData.setText(readString);

                        //Clear the editview for new entries
                        addbarcode.setText("");   
                      return true;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.send:

            final File dir = getFilesDir();

            final File shareFile = new File(dir, FileName);
            Uri u1  =   null;
            u1  =   Uri.fromFile(shareFile);

            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Person Details");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, u1);
            sendIntent.setType("text/csv");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

I even added required permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and even set the Java Build Path property from project properties.

Answer (score 1):

See [getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) docs.

> Gets the Android external storage directory. This directory may not
>   currently be accessible if it has been mounted by the user on their
>   computer, has been removed from the device, or some other problem has
>   happened. You can determine its current state with
>   getExternalStorageState().

Check it for `null` before accessing it.

Comment: I used this check but still no luck I added the following code in the one above                                                `Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

if(isSDPresent)
{
  // yes SD-card is present
}
else
{
 // Sorry
}

`                                                                    And its true but still no files.

Comment: Does any one know what am I missing? I really want get it over with. Thanks for the help.